# Wise to have one or two pet parrots in the same cage

Tags: parrots

Is it better to keep a single parrot as a pet, or more than one for company. I know there are many things to consider, but and overall answer will be better.

Comment: You shouldn't keep a parrot in a cage. Have them trained to stay within the house. You should always keep birds in pairs or more to avoid loneliness, which thereby increases its life span.

Answer (score 1):

Parrots should *always* be kept at least as a pair. They are highly social animals, and a human just cannot replace that.
Also, keep in mind that most commercial cages are realyl too small for even one parrot, let alone 2. To give a parrot a happy life, you should more be thinkign about a room the parrot can move freely in, with the cage as a "save house" to retreat to.